# can't find my class when i use classLoader.loadClass(completeClassName);

Tags: android

I use code
// name of the DEX file
String dexFile = "/classes.jar";

```
            // Get the path to the SD card
            File f = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +  dexFile);
            if (f.exists()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "file exist");
            }
            // optimized directory, the application and package directory
            final File optimizedDexOutputPath = getDir("dex", 0);


            // DexClassLoader to get the file and write it to the optimised directory
            DexClassLoader classLoader = new DexClassLoader(f.getAbsolutePath(),
            optimizedDexOutputPath.getAbsolutePath(),null, getClassLoader());
            // The classpath is created for the new class
            String completeClassName = "com.test.mylibrary.UpgradeVerifcaiton";
            String methodToInvoke = "playTest";

            try {
                Class<?> myClass = classLoader.loadClass(completeClassName);
                Object obj = (Object)myClass.newInstance();
                Method m = myClass.getMethod(methodToInvoke);
                String s = ""+m.invoke(obj);
                makeToast(s);
```

this line  **Class<?> myClass = classLoader.loadClass(completeClassName);** is throw exception that class in not found

please advise

Comment: You sure this part `"com.test.mylibrary.UpgradeVerifcaiton"` looks alright?

Comment: can you explain , this is the name of my class and it package name

Comment: are you sure it's `UpgradeVerifcaiton` instead of `UpgradeVerification` ? If you made a typo, then it's perfectly fine and expected to get the exception you're getting.

Comment: I change my class name to MainActivity and it still not find my class.
even if I call to classLoader.getPackages() i get null. 
any idea?